# How to get the message property from enum

Tags: java, jsf

I have an enumeration:

```
    public enum Gender {

       F("Female"),

       M("Male"),

       E("Either");

       private final String description;

       Gender(final String description) {
            this.description = description;
       }

       public String getDescription() {
            return description;
       }
    }
```

a message property:

```
    StudyLevel.B=Begin (1-3 semesters)
    StudyLevel.M=Middle (4-6 semesters)
    StudyLevel.E=End (7 and more semesters)
```

a bean:

```
   private Gender[] genders = Gender.values();
   public Gender[] getGenders() {
      return genders;
   }

   public void setGenders(Gender[] genders) {
      this.genders = genders;
   }
```

and my xhtml file:

```
    <p:selectOneRadio id="gender" value="#{cc.attrs.offer.selectedGender}" required="true">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{offerBean.genders}" var="p" itemLabel="#{p.class.simpleName.concat('.').concat(p.name())}"/>
    </p:selectOneRadio>
```

The output text of the selectItems is StudyLevel.B, StudyLevel.M and StudyLevel.E, but not Begin (1-3 semesters) and so on. How could I properly fetch it?

Comment: This got it working!

        <p:selectOneRadio id="gender" value="#{cc.attrs.offer.selectedGender}" required="true">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{offerBean.genders}" var="p" itemLabel="#{amsg.handleGetObject(p.class.simpleName.concat('.').concat(p.name()))}" />
                    </p:selectOneRadio>

Comment: You could add this as an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: And please improve the code indention.

Comment: you can use omnifaces o:importConstants instead of writing a offerBean to access the enum objects

Comment: he cant add an answer for 12 hours or something... :)

Comment: I improved the indentations and I will post my answer in 6 hours :)